# JQuery dynamically added javascripts tags close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm using javascript to dynamically add new tabs in jquery. I use the following code:

```
$("#mytabs1").tabs("add","list.action","New Tab");
```

My question is how i can add the close button (x button) to those dynamically added tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually an example to achieve this on the [jQuery ui tabs demo pages](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation).

Use the `tabTemplate` property:

> HTML template from which a new tab is created and added. The
>   placeholders #{href} and #{label} are replaced with the url and tab
>   label that are passed as arguments to the add method

Here's the code from the site:

```
var $tabs = $( "#tabs").tabs({
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    add: function( event, ui ) {
        var tab_content = $tab_content_input.val() || "Tab " + tab_counter + " content.";
        $( ui.panel ).append( "<p>" + tab_content + "</p>" );
    }
});

// close icon: removing the tab on click
// note: closable tabs gonna be an option in the future - see http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/3924
$( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live( "click", function() {
    var index = $( "li", $tabs ).index( $( this ).parent() );
    $tabs.tabs( "remove", index );
});
```

In your implementation, you should not use `.live()` but **delegate()** or **on()**. Something like:

```
$('#tabs').on('click', 'span.ui-icon-close', function() {
    var index = $( "li", $tabs ).index( $( this ).parent() );
    $tabs.tabs( "remove", index );
});
```

Comment: but how to append the x button at first?

Comment: What do you mean "at first" ? For tabs already in the markup ? Use the same markup as in the `tabTemplate` property.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs do not inherently have an x button. If you are adding an x button to your tabs somewhere else, and would like this same x button added to new tabs you add, you could try using the tabsadd event:

```
$("#mytabs1").tabs({
   add: function(event, ui) { 
      //your code that adds the custom x button to the new tab here
   }
});
```

Comment: You tell me, you didn't post any other code...I don't know how you're adding the close icon to the tabs. The current tabs widget does not include close icons so how are you adding a close icon to the others?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select immediately new added tab:

```
var $tabs = $('#tabsid').tabs({
            add: function(event, ui) {
                $tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
            }
        });
```

this will not work..